# Starting Apache Nifi process group from CMD

Tags: cmd, apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry, process-group

In Apache Nifi, is there any command to start particular process group from Command Prompt?

Comment: Nope, except NiFi service start/stop. You need to use NiFi REST APIs.

Comment: why it's NO? it should be yes it's possible - using nifi rest api ;)

Comment: Able to set the API

Comment: @daggett - I thought OP was looking for out-of-box NiFi CLI like functionality!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using curl commands

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).